# Change how a get url looks

Tags: php, mysql, forms, get

I am trying to make a dynamic user page such as reddit for example where you can go to reddit.com/u/bob and it will show the user page for bob. I want to do the same with my page instead of making it reddit.com/u?user=bob I want to make it like how reddit does reddit.com/u/bob. Could someone please tell me how to accomplish that. I cannot seem to find any methods that are published on the Internet for accomplishing that.

This is all done using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: learn about mod_rerewrite rules for apache server. Normally it's done in .htaccess file

Comment: This is probably because you won't be doing it in PHP. I believe that this comes down to the configuration of your virtual server. So can you let us know if you're using Apache or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$  /u.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Im getting an internal server error when trying that with a url such as localhost/u/bob. As a note I am using a .htaccess rewrite so the removing of php endings is causing an issue. Is there a way to make it work with this RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: Becouse $1.php wil mean Bob.php if you did something like /u/Bob try user.php?username=$1

Answer (score 0):

You need use .htaccess, it can control your url style.

Tutorial:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Please provide all the needed info on here so you will still have a valid answer once the link dies.